# Javascript - sort by with arrays of variable length

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Assume I have an array of options to sort by multiple scores, and those scores are an array of variable length

```js
[
  #[Label, scores]
  ["Label6", [1]
  ["Label5", [1,5]
  ["Label2", [0,1,3,5],
  ["Label1", [0,1,2]
  ["Label3", [0,1,4],
  ["Label4", [1,4]
]
```

I want to sort this list by evaluating array elements one by one. IE. I will first sort (ascending) by the `score[0]`, then `score[i+1]` if it exists, etc. When `score[i]` does not exist, it should be considered as an infinite value (appear at the bottom)

This could gives the following output on the previous data :

```js
list = [
  #[Label, scores]
  ["Label1", [0,1,2]  
  ["Label2", [0,1,3,5],
  ["Label3", [0,1,4],
  ["Label4", [1,4]
  ["Label5", [1,5]
  ["Label6", [1]
]
```

How can I write this function ? Is there a native/ES6 (or lodash/underscore) `sortBy()` function like we have in other languages ? (for example in Ruby you would simply `list.sort_by(&:last)` to get this effect). Or does it need to be implemented manually ?

Comment: Take a look at the [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.

Comment: @Kobe I'm can't see any example of what I'm trying to achieve in the doc of the `.sort` function. All solutions I came across involved something like `sort((a,b) => if a[0] - b[0], a[1] - b[1], ...` but what happens when an "item of sort criteria" can be of variable length ?

Comment: Then you'd write the callback function accordingly. I'll start on an answer now, but it seems quite difficult

Comment: I could convert scores to a string, then join them and just perform an alphabetical sort... but then I'd be dead if my scores were higher than 9 and that could be the case.

Comment: So you want `0, 1, 2` to appear  _after_ `0, 1, 2, 3`?

Comment: yes @georg absolutely ! I forgot to include this case in my example but it is exactly as you said

Comment: You want `[0, , 2]` to appear _after_ `[0, 1, 2]`? (regarding non-existing elements)

Comment: @Robert ideally I would want null values to count as infinite. Since my scores are bounded, I could very easily replace this null value by a default very high value, so it's not really a problem here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take the arrays, and sort by same index values.

At start take the minimum length of both arrays as the length for iterating the values and to prevent to take `undefined`.

If the delta of two values of same index is not zero, return the delta, otherwise proceed with the next index.

If all indices are visited without a former return, all value at the same index are equal until the minimum length of both arrays. In this case return the delta of the length of both in switched order, because the longer array should come first.

```js
var array = [["Label6", [1, 5]], ["Label2", [0, 1, 3, 5]], ["Label1", [0, 1, 2]], ["Label3", [0, 1, 4]], ["Label5", [1, 5, 2]], ["Label4", [1, 4]]];

array.sort(([, a], [, b]) => {
    var delta,
        index = 0,
        length = Math.min(a.length, b.length);

    while (index < length) {
        delta = a[index] - b[index];
        if (delta) return delta;
        index++;
    }

    return b.length - a.length;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

There is the `array.sort()` function, which takes in a sorting algorithm and sorts the array for you based on that. all you have to do is implement the sorting for only 2 arguments.

here is what i'd do in your case:

```
list.sort( list1, list2 => {
  let i = 0, iterations = min(list1.length, list2.length);
  for( i = 0; i<iterations; i++ ){
    if( list1[i] < list2[i] ) return -1;
    if( list1[i] > list2[i] ) return 1;
  }
  if( list1.length === list2.length ) return 0;
  if( i === list1.length ) return -1;
  if( i === list2.length ) return 1;
}
```